# `pip list` listing packages which are actually not installed

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-venv

I think I found "a feature", where under some weird conditions `pip` lists a package as installed even though it isn't. If someone could explain me what is going on - that would be nice. Here are steps to reproduce:

1. setup two python environments: `$ python3 -m venv env_1 && python3 -m venv env_2`
2. get any normal python package with setup.py for the installation, I personally used the first thing I found on the internet: `$ git clone https://github.com/BillMills/python-package-example.git`
3. activate env_1: `$ . env_1/bin/activate`
4. install the package you got **as a development package**: `$ pip install -e python-package-example`
5. deactivate env_1, activate env_2: `$ deactivate && . env_2/bin/activate`
6. go inside of the package you just installed for env_1 and list the installed packages (for the env_2): `$ cd python-package-example && pip list`

For whatever reason this shows python-package-example as already installed. Works only while you are inside of this folder though, and only after you installed the thing once as a development package.

P.S. `python3 -m pip show python-package-example` in `env_1` shows:

```
Name: python-package-example
Version: 0.1
Summary: An example python package
Home-page: https://github.com/BillMills/python-package-example
Author: Bill Mills
Author-email: myemail@example.com
License: MIT
Location: /home/esrlabs/Workspace/testing/bash/test/python-package-example
Requires: numpy
Required-by:
```

Same query in `env_2` returns `WARNING: Package(s) not found: python-package-example` outside of `python-package-example`, and return the same thing as for `env_1` while in that folder.

Comment: Show us the output of `python3 -m pip show python-package-example` in each environment.

Comment: @sinoroc I updated the question with the output.

Comment: Yeah, there's definitely something surprising going on... I kind of can reproduce something similar. If I am in the same directory as a `something.egg-info` directory, and I run `pip show something`, I get a _warning package not found_ as expected, but `python -m pip show something` delivers the valid output for this project, which is unexpected.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce:

```
(env_2) test-venv $$ cd python-package-example/
(env_2) python-package-example $$ pip list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        19.3.1 
setuptools 41.4.0 
wheel      0.33.6
```

`python-package-example` is not listed.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to reproduce it at home with Arch + python 3.7, could not do it...
Here with Ubuntu 18.04 + python 3.6 it works just as I described.
So I guess it might even be not a problem with pip itself, but something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably related to this [pip *issue*](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6558).

The `python_package_example.egg-info/` in the current working directory is somehow picked up and registered as an installed project.

I wouldn't get all too worried about it. As said in the comments of the previously mentioned issue, that is why the [*src layout*](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/#the-structure) is a very good thing and in most cases mitigates this issue and many other similar.